# Bulk data entry using two different forms, and what to call them?

Tags: usability, forms, data-entry

I'm designing a database system for certifying training test results. There are a variety of ways data could be entered, which I've narrowed down to 2 different forms for ease of use. In most cases many records will be added at one time.

The first form (which is currently accessed via link called "Add Multiple Different Records") looks like this:
[image]

The second form (which is currently accessed via link called "Add One (or Many Similar) Records") looks like this:
[image]

The main difference is that the first form allows the user to specify a different completion date, supervisor and notes for each user, while the second form adds the same data for ALL users. I'm struggling with what to call the links used to access these forms. As above, I'm currently using "Add Multiple Different Records" and "Add One (or Many Similar) Records" - but I feel like neither would be intuitive to someone who has never used the system before. Is there a better way to label these forms so that users can tell at a glance which form they need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the issue is with the naming, but with the fact that you have two different entry forms which only differ in one very small aspect.

Instead I would focus more on incorporating the functionality of the second form with the first.

For example, the easiest solution would be the have the values of the *Date*, *Supervisor* and *Notes* fields remain after pressing the *Add* button. For this, you would also want to make the fields clear when the users select them, so they don't have to manually delete the value to change it.

Or a better solution if you only want your users to be able to paste IDs is to turn the *ID* field into a multi-line field which can be pasted into. Ensure it's taller than the other fields to help users recognise it's a multi-line field. For example:

[image: Multi-line field in a data entry form]

If your IDs are fixed length, you can make so that it automatically moves to a new line when that length is reached, which immediately shows the user they can enter another ID.

Comment: Thanks, Joel. I like this idea - except for one thing that I didn't mention in my question: The second form is necessary because 2 out of 9 training tests have a LOT more data fields on that form. (The first quick-entry form is not even available for those 2 tests.) Basically I have 7 tests that are pretty much identical, data-wise, and 2 outliers that throw the whole design off.

Comment: If the second form is available for all of the training tests, how about using that one instead of the first form? Then you only require one link: *Add Record*.

In addition, you could treat the first form as a secondary input method and only display it below tables of records, providing users a convenient way of adding data while browsing records. This would not require it's own link to access.

Comment: I like the idea of moving the first for as secondary footer input on the record display page and only have one Add Records page, so I'm going to run with that. Thanks for the feedback!